# Apache ssl - Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client?

Tags: apache, ssl

Apache 2.2.22
Does not work on customer input certificate. Although based on the same config file in another organization and it works!

Here's an excerpt from the log file:

```
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1884): OpenSSL: Write: SSLv3 read client certificate B
[debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv3 read client certificate B
[error] [client 10.*.*.*] Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?
```

We think, what problem in web server certificate(or client certificate), but not idea how it test.

Sorry for my poor english.